# I Have Issue with Flutter Apk

Tags: flutter, dart, build, apk, flutter-apk

When I run my Flutter app in debug mode, it works fine. However, when I build the release version and try to install the APK, a warning dialog appears, which is not seen with other APKs from different projects. There are also cases where I see a blank screen after installing the new APK.
It appears that the issues started occurring after upgrading to Flutter version 3.10.0.

I am also seeing this message when I build APK
**Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 1384 bytes (99.9% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --n
o-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.**
Which I don't see in previous version of flutter. so What is the issue

Here are the Warning Dialog.
[First Image when I Click on Apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhSr3.jpg)
in the first image if I click on more detail so I can install APK
but the issue is that why I am seeing this dialog after upgrading to Flutter 3.10.0
[Second Image after installing Apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5uK7.jpg)

Here is my pubspec

```
name: project
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.0 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg



  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats due to a security feature called "Google Play Protect". this could trigger due to various reasons. could be the google play is simply playing it safe. Or may be due to the app is signed with a debug Certificate if you haven't add a proper signing certificate. you can learn more from [Google Documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2812853?hl=en)

Comment: I turn Off Google Play Protect Now I don't see this Issue. Is it ok to turn off Google Play Protect.

Comment: Not really. You should not turn off Google Play protect. instead you can ignore the popup. It wont interfere with the app's functions